# In Python, is it possible to overload Numpy's memmap to delete itself when the memmap object is no longer referenced?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use memmap when certain data doesn't fit in memory and employ memmap's ability to trick code into thinking it's just an ndarray. To further expand on this way of using memmap I was wondering if it would be possible to overload memmap's dereference operator to delete the memmap file.

So for example:

```
from tempfile import mkdtemp
import os.path as path
filename = path.join(mkdtemp(), 'tmpfile.dat')
{
    out = np.memmap(filename, dtype=a.dtype, mode='w+', shape=a.shape)
}
# At this point out is out of scope, so the overloaded 
# dereference function would delete tmpfile.dat
```

Does this sound feasible/has this been done? Is there something I am not thinking of?

Thank you!

Comment: "Dereference operator"?

Comment: `{` `}`?! `from __future__ import braces`...

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't rather use a `with` context manager? `with` is how Python does scope-based resource management; it's the closest thing to C++'s RAII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just delete the file after it has been opened by `np.memmap`
the file will then be deleted by the system after the last reference to the file descriptor is closed.

python temporary files work like this and can very conveniently be used with the `with` context manger construct:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    # file gone now from the filesystem 
    # but f still holds a reference so it still exists and uses space (see /prof<pid>/fd)
    # open it again (will not work on windows)
    x = np.memmap(f.name, dtype=np.float64, mode='w+', shape=(3,4))
# file path is unlinked but exists on disk with the open file reference in x
del x
# now all references are gone and the file is properly deleted
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Even before calling `del x`, `os.path.exists(x.filename)` is `False`. `x` only has reference to `f.name`, a string, not the `f` object itself.

Comment: the path does not exist anymore, but the file is not deleted until the last reference to it has been removed. `x` holds a reference to the file, that is how np.memmap works, it opens what `f.name` points to, so it needs to be deleted. It has nothing to do with the python object `f` which is removed by the context manager, this is a property of the OS filesystem.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Could you possibly change the text to make this clear? Maybe `# f reference is gone now but x still has a reference` -> `# file path is unlinked but exists on disk with the open file reference`?

Answer (score 2):

A case if we do not want to use with and just have some class that handles it for us:

```
class tempmap(np.memmap):
    """
    Extension of numpy memmap to automatically map to a file stored in temporary directory.
    Usefull as a fast storage option when numpy arrays become large and we just want to do some quick experimental stuff.
    """
    def __new__(subtype, dtype=np.uint8, mode='w+', offset=0,
                shape=None, order='C'):
        ntf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
        self = np.memmap.__new__(subtype, ntf, dtype, mode, offset, shape, order)
        self.temp_file_obj = ntf
        return self

    def __del__(self):
        if hasattr(self,'temp_file_obj') and self.temp_file_obj is not None:
            self.temp_file_obj.close()
            del self.temp_file_obj

def np_as_tmp_map(nparray):
    tmpmap = tempmap(dtype=nparray.dtype, mode='w+', shape=nparray.shape)
    tmpmap[...] = nparray
    return tmpmap


def test_memmap():
    """Test, that deleting a temp memmap also deletes the file."""
    x = np_as_tmp_map(np.zeros(10, 10), np.float))
    name = copy(x.temp_file_obj.name)
    del x
    x = None
    assert not os.path.isfile(name)
```