# Numpy memmap with file deletion

Tags: python, numpy, mmap, temporary-files

Is it possible to have a Numpy memmap file who's file will be deleted when the memmap array is garbage collected?

I have tried:

```
import tempfile
import numpy as np
arr = np.memmap(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(), mode='w+',
                shape=(10, 10), dtype=np.int)
os.path.exists(arr.filename) # False
```

But it appears the reference to the temporary file isn't kept so is deleted.

I don't want to use a context manager on the temporary file, as I want to be able to return the array from a function and have the file live until the array is no longer used.

NB: similar question here: [In Python, is it possible to overload Numpy's memmap to delete itself when the memmap object is no longer referenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178460/in-python-is-it-possible-to-overload-numpys-memmap-to-delete-itself-when-the-m) but the asker exhibits poor knowledge of Python scoping and the tempfile module.

Comment: Looks like there are some tricky interactions between `tempfile` and `memmap`.  If the tempfile is created first, or I use my own filename, the file exists, both to `os.path` and an OS file manager.  Created your way the file might not exist outside of a memory buffer.  Experiment also with `delete=False`.

Comment: It looks like your brief discussion on the linked SO answered your question.  It's all tied up in the interaction of the operating system and how `tempfile` creates the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, [jtaylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24219413/3903368) to the question originally linked is correct. So the code:

```
import tempfile
import numpy as np
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as ntf:
    temp_name = ntf.name
    arr = np.memmap(ntf, mode='w+',
                    shape=(10, 10), dtype=np.int)
print(arr)
```

Works as desired, even though `os.path.exists(temp_name)` is false, because of the way the OS manages files. The file path (`temp_name`) is unlinked, and no longer accessible through the filesystem, however the actual file disk usage will remain available until the open file is closed, which the memmap object will keep.